# Angular 11 Manual Routing Doesn't Work On Mobile

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular11

I seem to be running into a weird issue with the Angular Router (11.2.12).

When typing a URL manually into the address bar on mobile (iOS), NavigationStart will fire but no other events therefore causing the app not to navigate.

This works fine on desktop browsers however.

Has anyone else run into this issue before?